# What are these white bugs that leave white stains on my cars and driveway?

Tags: pest-control, aphids

I have these white bugs that seem to be falling down from the tree over where I park my cars. They have feathery tendrils and are staining our cars with white drops.

Any idea as to what these bugs are and how to get rid of them?

The first picture is what I originally saw. This had a larger body, with long white thread-like tendrils.

The next picture had what looks like a [woolly aphid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eriosomatinae) (on the left) and a variation of the first type I saw. This is the first time I saw one with wings. The one on the right has a very small body, but very similar tendrils to the first.

[image: white bugs][image: two other variations]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The description sounds like woolly aphids, and from some combined detective work are most likely [Woolly Alder Aphids](http://www.google.com/search?q=woolly%20alder%20aphid&hl=en&biw=1192&bih=792&prmd=ivns&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=bBvpTbePCs_pgAfDtfHBAQ&sqi=2&ved=0CD8QsAQ).

One way to get rid of them would be to introduce a natural predator. Ladybugs could be your best bet - although then you may end up with a ladybug infestation. Amazon has them for [pretty cheap](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000MR6WRG) if you decide to go this route.

Comment: To follow up, I ordered 150 lady bugs from Amazon and released them as per the instructions included. It's been about 4 days now with no signs of any Aphids.